# How to use different JS output for different pages?

Tags: clojurescript

Let's say I have two pages which share much code, many libraries etc., but have some differences. For a concrete example, I include jQuery and in each page have different function in "document ready" (aka `$(function() { ... })`).

With JS that would be easy. I would include jQuery in each page, and have different piece of `<script>` on each page, or include `script-behind-page-A.js` in `pageA.html`, and `script-behing-page-B.js` in `pageB.html`.

How shall I achieve the same result with ClojureScript?

I suspect the compilation output is so big that it's best to have one big ball of JavaScript emitted by compiler. In that case, it clearly cannot have two different "document ready" functions.

Is the suggested flow to make the code consist mostly of functions that enable you to do things, few state variables initialized, and initialize each page individually with plain JS as needed?

Answer (score 5):

I think the recommended approach would be what is explained in this [ClojureScript tutorial by Mimmo Cosenza](https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs):

- Produce a single, large JS output file (so you optimize/gzip it when this goes live)
- Use different namespaces for the functions, make sure you export at least a single "entry-point function" for each page
- On each HTML file, call the desired "entry point function", like this:

  ```
  <!-- on the bottom of welcome.html -->
  <script src="js/output.js"></script>
  <script>myapp.welcome.init();</script>

  <!-- on the bottom of login.html -->
  <script src="js/output.js"></script>
  <script>myapp.login.init();</script>
  ```

This is explained on detail on the [part 6 of the tutorial](https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs/blob/master/doc/tutorial-06.md).